# Simple redirect with query not working

Tags: .htaccess

When I try to redirect like this, it's not working, and it's not redirecting.

```
Redirect 301 http://site.domain/file.php?query=q http://anothersite.domain/something.php
```

But without the query it works, and I want to know why? I want to redirect depending on queries.

```
Redirect 301 http://site.domain/file.php http://anothersite.domain/something.php
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no way do that using `Redirect` you have to use `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}   ^query=q$  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^file\.php$    http://anothersite.domain/something.php  [R=301,L]
```

For sending query string use `QSA`  flag.